# Adding Native Advance Admob Ad

Tags: android, admob

**The main question is - How can I get a unit ID for production instead of using the test unit ID**

Admob doesn't give me a option to select native ads? Here is a image with the 3 options that are given to select from:

[image: admob optioin]

What am I missing? Should I select native ads from another place? I surely can't use the test test unit id. I know that Native Express is discontinued, this is for Native Advance.

I followed the guideline on [support.google](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7187428?hl=en) and the image above is mentioned in step 6 in that guide `Click Select for the Native ad format`, but as you can see there is no option to select the native ad format.

Also, on [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-advanced) they only talk about using the test unit id when testing and don't mention what unit Id should be used for production.

> The easiest way to load test ads is to use our dedicated test ad unit ID for Native Advanced on Android:
>
> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110
>
> It's been specially configured to return test ads for every request, and you're free to use it in your own apps while coding, testing, and debugging. Just make sure you replace it with your own ad unit ID before publishing your app.

---

I now asked a question on groups.google.com and on googlesamples github page with the hopes of getting a answer. So far no response.

---

**My conclusion to this subject:**

After a lot of questions, emails and research I have found that native advance is STILL in beta release and only available to a small group of publishers, the VIPs if you will.

Somehow I misread this on AdMob's website:

> Note: Native Ads Advanced is currently in a limited release. If you are interested in participating, reach out to your account manager to discuss the possibility.

So with native express discontinued and stop serving ads on 1 March 2018 I would have thought that AdMob would make native advance available to all publishers. Unfortunately that is not the case.

So, I'm sorry Google AdMob but I will have to look at other options. Not like they care ;)

Comment: means do you want to get test unit ad ID?

Comment: @Dharmishtha I'm currently using the test unit ad ID, I want to create a native ad in admob to get a production ID.

Comment: Thank you so much. Thought I was insane. You can use the ad unit id from the sample code if you still want to implement and test it. For some reason it's production ads though and not test ads but I guess only that test account will be banned for it anyway